# Jquery get all checked values only from list of checkboxs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new in jQuery and html. I am trying to get all checked values from list of checkboxs but my scripts returns all values rather then checked.

Following my html:

```
<input type="button" value="Show selected" onclick="return false" class="showSelectedOnly">

<table>

<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" class="order_row" data-order-id="20161004-135848" name="sel20161004-135848" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" class="order_row" data-order-id="20161004-135848" name="sel20161004-135848" ></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" class="order_row" data-order-id="20161004-135848" name="sel20161004-135848" ></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

My js scripts:

```
  $(".showSelectedOnly").click(function(){

    $('.order_row:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
      var sThisVal = $(this).attr("data-order-id");
      alert(sThisVal);
    });
  });
```

Please let me know why my scripts not returning only checked values.

Comment: You code should work

Comment: @Satpal yeah working i checked

Comment: working fiddle . Work fine . May be you forget to include js or your code is outside of document.ready. https://jsfiddle.net/shree/3k7tjecw/

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using  $('.order_row:checkbox:checked') use only $('.order_row:checked') check below answer hope it will help-

```js
 $(".showSelectedOnly").click(function(){

    $('.order_row:checked').each(function () {
      var sThisVal = $(this).attr("data-order-id");
      alert(sThisVal);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Show selected" onclick="return false" class="showSelectedOnly">

<table>

<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" class="order_row" data-order-id="20161004-135848" name="sel20161004-135848" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" class="order_row" data-order-id="20161004-135848" name="sel20161004-135848" ></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" class="order_row" data-order-id="20161004-135848" name="sel20161004-135848" ></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just store all your checked data in a array as follows

```
$(".showSelectedOnly").click(function(){
  var selected = [];
  $('.order_row:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
    var sThisVal = $(this).attr("data-order-id");
    selected.push(sThisVal);
  });
  alert(selected);
});
```